# How do I extract a series of numbers along with a single letter followed by another series of numbers?

Tags: excel

The problem that I'm facing is that I have an entire column that has text separated by `_` that contains pixel size that I want to be able to extract but currently can't. For example:

```
           A                                  
Example_Number_320x50_fifty_five
Example_Number_One_300x250_hundred
Example_Number_two_fifty_728x49
```

I have tried using Substitute function to grab the numbers which works but only grabs the numbers when I need something like: `320x50` instead I'm getting `0`, as I'm not sure how to exactly extract something like this. If it was consistent I could easily do `LEFT` or `RIGHT` formula's to grab it but as you can see the data varies.

The result that I'm looking for is something along the lines of:

```
           A                        |          B   
Example_Number_320x50_fifty_five    |       320x50
Example_Number_One_300x250_hundred  |       300x200
Example_Number_two_fifty_728x49     |       728x49
```

Any help would be much appreciated! If any further clarification is needed please let me know and I'll try to explain as best as I can!

-Maykid

Comment: I guess you can use regex https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22542834/how-to-use-regular-expressions-regex-in-microsoft-excel-both-in-cell-and-loops

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would probably use a Regular Expressions UDF to accomplish this.

- First, open up the VBE by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd>.
- Right-Click on **VBAProject** > **Insert** > **Module**

Then you can paste the following code in your module:

```vb
Option Explicit

Public Function getPixelDim(RawTextValue As String) As String

    With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
        .Pattern = "\d+x\d+"
        If .Test(RawTextValue) Then
            getPixelDim = .Execute(RawTextValue)(0)
        End If
    End With

End Function
```

Back to your worksheet, you would use the following formula:

```
=getPixelDim(A1)
```

[image]

---

Looking at the pattern `\d+x\d+`, an escaped `d` (`\d`) refers to *any digit*, a `+` means *one or more of `\d`*, and the `x` is just a literal letter x. This is the pattern you want to capture as your function's return value.

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

Gosh, K Davis was just so fast! Here's an alternate method with similar concept.

Create a module and create a user defined function like so.

```
Public Function GetPixels(mycell As Range) As String

    Dim Splitter As Variant
    Dim ReturnValue As String
    Splitter = Split(mycell.Text, "_")

    For i = 0 To UBound(Splitter)
        If IsNumeric(Mid(Splitter(i), 1, 1)) Then
            ReturnValue = Splitter(i)
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    GetPixels = ReturnValue

End Function
```

In your excel sheet, type in B1 the formula `=GetPixels(A1)` and you will get 320x50.

## How do you create a user defined function?

**Developer tab**

Use this URL to add Developer tab if you don't have it: https://www.addintools.com/documents/excel/how-to-add-developer-tab.html

Click on the highlighted areas to get to Visual Basic for Applications (VBA) window.

[image]

**Create module**

Click Insert > Module and then type in the code.

[image]

**Use the user defined function**

[image]

Note how the user defined function is called.

Comment: Not only the code itself is functional, but the visuals are certainly great for those who are unfamiliar with the VBE. Well done putting this together