# Excel extraction filter cell

Tags: excel

I want to be able to get only desired data from  a cell
For example here is cell `A1`:

```
+1.5 (-175) (o/u 8.5) (+118)
```

I would like to get the value that is in the last parenthesis so new value should be `+118`

Comment: Is the last value always in parentheses?  Is the format of all cells (that you want to extract the last value out of) the same?

Comment: Yes the last value is always in parenthese.

Comment: Are there always 3 sets of parentheses in the cell?

Comment: Yes format is always the came for whole cell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this will find the last grouping of `()` and return what is in between regardless of location in the string or number of `()` pairs:

```
=LEFT(MID(A1,FIND("}}}",SUBSTITUTE(A1,"(","}}}",LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"(",""))))+1,999),FIND(")",MID(A1,FIND("}}}",SUBSTITUTE(A1,"(","}}}",LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"(",""))))+1,999))-1)
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

Answer (score 1):

You can create a user defined function like so:

```
Public Function GetLastNumber(C As Range)
    Data = Split(C.Text, "(")
    GetLastNumber = Replace(Data(UBound(Data)), ")", "")
End Function
```

Then, in B1 you can type `=GetLastNumber(A1)` to get `+118`

If you are unfamiliar with creating a user defined function, check out this answer: [How do I extract a series of numbers along with a single letter followed by another series of numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55835177) that has some pictures to illustrate that.

Answer (score 1):

If there are always 3 sets of values with parentheses, this formula will pull the value out of the 3rd set.

```
=MID(A1,FIND("(",A1,FIND("(",A1,FIND("(",A1,1)+1)+1)+1,LEN(A1)-FIND("(",A1,FIND("(",A1,FIND("(",A1,1)+1)+1)-1)
```